# c# How do i set a button Id and delete it later on?

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach, flowlayoutpanel

I'm having a little trouble with my program. I'm currently programming a friend request script and basically when the user receives a friend request, it will automatically add it to a `FlowLayoutPanel` and in each friend request, the user's name will show along with a accept and reject button. Here's the code:

```
foreach (object request in i.ToString())
{
    Label userName = new Label();
    Button accept = new Button();
    Button reject = new Button();
    accept.Click += Accept_Click;
    reject.Click += Reject_Click;
    userName.Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(dr["UserFirstName"].ToString() + " " + dr["UserLastName"].ToString());
    accept.Text = "Accept";
    reject.Text = "Reject";
    friendRequestPanel.Controls.Add(userName);
    friendRequestPanel.Controls.Add(accept);
    friendRequestPanel.Controls.Add(reject);
}
```

What it looks like:
[image: GUI]

Now the problem is, when the user either accepts or rejects a request, it seems to delete all of the labels and buttons. 
Code:

```
friendRequestPanel.Controls.Remove(UserName); // Label
friendRequestPanel.Controls.Remove(accept); // Button
friendRequestPanel.Controls.Remove(rejects); // Button
```

How would I assign an id to each button and label so I can remove it later on?
Something like: `friendRequestPanel.Controls.Remove(username[ID No]);`

Comment: You can store redundantly your references in a Dictionary<string, object>, and when you want to remove it, obtain the reference from the dictionary to request for the appropriate instance. Obviously, don't forget to remove it from the dictionary too.

Comment: If you just want to have an ID, you can use the Tag property, and look up for the appropriate in friendRequestPanel.Controls to obtain the reference you want to remove.

Comment: [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name(v=vs.110).aspx) property is for such usage. You can assign a name to control and then find it in `Controls` collection of its parent using that name.

Comment: Hi guys could you show me an example? Nothing seems to work... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a control for those buttons and create them dynamically. Store them into a `List<MyControl>` and remove the controls when needed. Because you'd like to 'group' them.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code a bit in order to simplify the code. Hope you find it useful.

```
        string[] tags = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };

        foreach (string request in tags)
        {
            Label userName = new Label();
            userName.Name = request;
            Button accept = new Button();
            accept.Name = request;

            Button reject = new Button();
            reject.Name = request;

            userName.Text = request;
            accept.Text = "Accept";
            reject.Text = "Reject";
            friendRequestPanel.Controls.Add(userName);
            friendRequestPanel.Controls.Add(accept);
            friendRequestPanel.Controls.Add(reject);
        }

        // Just remove the "B"s
        friendRequestPanel.Controls.RemoveByKey("B");
```

Obviously, this is not the best approach for what you want to do. But solves your problem.

Comment: How would I use int instead of string (Tags)?

Comment: You can't. Name is a String property. but you always can call integer.ToString() method to convert your integer in a string. Obviously, don't forget to convert the int you are looking for to string before try to remove it.